# Right way to get height of element in pixels (with all browsers?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Considering all current and also some old browsers still available in current market (such as IE6+), including mobile devices browsers, is safe to use

```
$(e).height() + 'px'
```

or

```
$(e).css('height'))
```

to get `height` of the element `e` in pixels? Are both above approaches equal or should I prefer to use one or other? Will be always size in pixels returned or it is not safe to claim that?

Comment: It depends on what version of jquery you are using. More recent versions do additional work with `.height()`, making `.css()` somewhat faster.

Comment: @KevinB yes but `.height()` always returns a unitless pixel value (a number, with no "px" at the end).

Comment: Yes, which you can of course fix with string concatenation, i wouldn't consider that much of a diff.

Comment: @KevinB - whatever version is needed, to support as much browsers, as possible (even those old, such as IE6)

Comment: @KevinB - isn't the additional work done in `.height()` exactly what makes it "safe to use"?

Comment: @KevinB I don't know if the `.css()` API does anything to "fix" percentage heights, or heights in "em" or "in" units for that matter.

Comment: Here's the full explanation: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/ I guess it really depends on what you want. the css height, or the actual height, since they could differ if you have the box-sizing css style set (which isn't supported in Ie6/7 anyway)

Comment: Yes, it's safe! Does it work in all browsers, don't know and don't care, it works in all browser most people would care about, and IE6 is not one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/height/

> > The difference between .css( "height" ) and .height() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .height() method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

and then,

> > Note that .height() will always return the content height, regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property. As of jQuery 1.8, this may require retrieving the CSS height plus box-sizing property and then subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when the element has box-sizing: border-box. To avoid this penalty, use .css( "height" ) rather than .height().

So, the evidence is contradictory -- looks like an evaluation of the specific use case is order.

Comment: There's also `.outerHeight()` and `.innerHeight()` for special situations.

Comment: _"the former returns a value with units intact"_ - This implies that the units might not be pixels, although I just did a quick test that showed the jQuery converted the height to pixels - which in my opinion is not keeping the units "intact".

Comment: But will `css` always return value with `px` units? I want to eliminate a risk of possibility to get result in other units, e.g. `1.2em`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> The difference between .css( "height" ) and .height() is that the
>   latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the
>   former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The
>   .height() method is recommended when an element's height needs to be
>   used in a mathematical calculation.

It is described here:
http://api.jquery.com/height/